# Why is Entity Framework Core 7 not adding columns to select from database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a very simple and standard table which I'm trying to get data out of EF Core 7.

I have this simple model class:

```
[Table("APComment")]
public class ApplicationCommentModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("recid")]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("InvoiceNo")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string InvoiceNumber;

    [Column("InvoiceLineNo")]
    [Required]
    public int InvoiceLineNumber;

    [MaxLength(988)]
    public string? CommentText;
}
```

And I'm trying to load it with a simple

```
public async Task<List<ApplicationCommentModel>> GetAllAsync()
{
    using (var context = _contextCreator())
    {
        var comments = context.ApplicationComments.ToList();
        return comments;
    }
}
```

However, when I look at the query output going to the DB, I'm seeing only this, where are the other columns?

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (37ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [a].[recid]
FROM [APComment] AS [a]
The program '[27792] CompanyAddressMaintenance.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
```

What I'm expecting to see if select a.recid, invoiceno, invoicelineno, commenttext from APComment but I'm not. What am I doing wrong? I just don't understand why this is happening?

I'm using EF Core 7.0.10 libs

Comment: Does this indicate that an *exception* is being thrown?  If you surround the operations with a try/catch structure, do you catch and observe an exception?

Comment: Do you have a [mre]? Can you please post it somewhere like github?

Comment: Howdy. 

This was the minimal example I could come up with. Thank you Guru for trying.

No exception was\is being thrown David. Thank you for asking.

Comment: @PHenry: When you debug, does `comments` successfully contain a list of these objects?  Are the objects in that list populated only with the `Id` value, or with other values as well?

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for reply. Well....in my db, comments doesn't have any data.  :< BUT the other rows ARE coming back with populated data now! Which was the main reason for the question.

Comment: Can I ask, why the -1 vote? Is that question THAT bad? I didn't think so. Important enough to stop my dev to figure it out.

Also, why are there edits? Isn't it more important to try to help with solving the issue than it is to correct grammar? Not that I care, but the aggressive judging\correcting does make me think twice about asking on this forum. Is that really desired?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: @PHenry: I wouldn't worry much about the votes.  In particular this question is very close to just a "typo" since the working property was in fact a property while the others were just fields.  (I didn't notice it at first either.)  It may be helpful to future visitors with the same issue, but may need to be worded differently to call attention to that difference and ask about that difference.  Since it was just something unnoticed, it's more of just a typo.  As for the edits, definitely don't concern yourself with those unless they damage the question in any way.  Edits are encouraged.

Comment: Thank you David very much for the follow up. Much appreciated. Have a good weekend.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the link. I had gone through a couple of Pluralsight vids from Julie Lerman (the EF Godess herself LOL), but I still missed out on the gets and sets. Simple enouigh mistake, trying to work faster. :< Thank you Paul for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! PHEW! My problem is I assumed setting up the field property was enough....it didn't complain at me, nor did it give me compile errors. However, the missing link was I didn't out "{get; set;} at the end of each property. After doing that, I can see the columns coming up in the select.
GOT IT!

This is what I mean for comparison.

```
[Key]
[Column("recid")]
[Required]
public int Id **{ get; set; }**

[Column("InvoiceNo")]
[Required]
[MaxLength(8)]
public string InvoiceNumber **{ get; set; }**

[Column("InvoiceLineNo")]
[Required]
public int InvoiceLineNumber **{ get; set; }**

[MaxLength(988)]
public string? CommentText **{ get; set; }**
```

Comment: *"I assumed setting up the field property was enough"*. There's no such thing as a "field property". A field is a field and a property is a property. Without the getter and/or setter, it's just a field, i.e. a member variable. The getter and/or setter is what makes it a property. Properties are implemented as methods, which allows additional logic like validation and raising events. As you've discovered, only properties are mapped to columns by EF.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that..the hard way. Thanks. I did think about it more last night and realized about the methods being generated by the compile for gets and sets. Thanks.